# Uniform convergence on $R_0$ implies uniform convergence on R

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

**Problem:**
Consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which converges pointwise to some function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, we assume that the convergence is uniform on $\mathbb{R}_0 =\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Can you conclude that $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly on whole $\mathbb{R}$?

**Attempt:**
I suggest this will be true? But I don't really know how start. First I tried something in the fashion of: for all $x\neq 0$ we have
$$|f_n(0)-f(0)| \le |f_n(0)-f_n(x)| +|f_n(x) -f(x)| +|f(x)-f(0)|$$
and then making each of these terms small enough. However, this won't work for the first and last term where continuity would be required. So this strategy will fail?
A second attempt I had in mind was proving that we can somehow extent the uniform convergence of $\mathbb{R}_0$ to its closure $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't know how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$.  You know $\lvert f_n(0)-f(0)\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N_0$ from pointwise convergence, and you know for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_0$ $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N_1$ from uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}_0$.  Can you combine the two bounds $n>N_0$ and $n>N_1$?

Comment: So we can simply take $N= \max (N_1, N_2) $ to have for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$ for $n\ge N$?

Comment: Yes, you have it!

Comment: Okay, didn't expect it to be that straightforward. But what if $(f_n)_n$ would convergence uniformly for $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_1, x_2 , ... \}$, can we then still extent this uniform convergence to the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ or when does it starts to fail?

Comment: Finitely many points is OK, infinitely many points you can get counterexample such as $f_n=1_{x_n}$.